# django forms ajax get client's data from db

Tags: ajax, django, forms, autofill

Hello im trying to fill the field "amount" that cointains the price of the payment_plan, and the payment_plan is part of the client information. I've been searching and the way to do it is implementing Ajax, but i have not found an example with django forms, every solution is really diferent from mine.

this is the model:

```
class Payment_Plans(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Clients(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, default=0)
    payment_plan = models.ForeignKey(Payment_Plans, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id

class Payments(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients)  
    month_from = models.DateField(default='1111-01-01')
    month_to = models.DateField(default='1111-01-01')
    amount = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.month_from.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

this is my payment form:

```
class PaymentsForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    month_from = forms.DateField(widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD", "pickTime": False}), label="Mes desde")
    month_to = forms.DateField(widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD", "pickTime": False}), label="Mes Hasta")
    amount = forms.IntegerField(label="Monto")
    client =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Clients.objects.all(), label="Cliente")

    class Meta:
        model=Payments
        fields = ('month_from', 'month_to', 'amount', 'client')
```

This is the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap %}

{% block titulo %}Realizar Pago{% endblock%}

{% block encabezado %} 
    <h1>Realizar Pago</h1>
    <!-- Para el datepicker -->
    {{ form.media }}
{% endblock%}

{% block contenido %} 
    <form id='form' method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ form.client|bootstrap }}
            {{ form.month_from|bootstrap }}
            {{ form.month_to|bootstrap }}
            {{ form.amount|bootstrap }}
            {{ form.days_left|bootstrap }}
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Pagar' class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>  
    </form>
{% endblock%}
```

this should work like this:

1) the user selects the Client (right now its just a select box, in future autocomplete field)

2) the form should look into the client's payment_plan and then into the payment_plan price.

3) field should be filled with the price

how can i achive this? is it possible with django forms? shall i write manually the template instead of ussing tags like {{forms.client}}? if thats the case, how do i get the Clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AJAX, you just need to know the fields' ids. Set an onchange (or `.change()` if you're using jquery) event on the 'client' field that sends the client id to a view, for instance, '/client-price' that will use it to query for the other price. Something like:

```
$( "#client" ).change(function() {
  clientID = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET", // if you choose to use a get, could be a post
      url: "/client-price/?id=" + clientID,
      success: function(data) {
          $( "#amount" ).val(data.price);
});
```

The view/url would take the id. [This post](https://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1508) shows how you'd want to format your view to send back a json response.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks onyeka! after some research with ajax and json the code looks like this:

view: (remember to import from django.http import JsonResponse)

```
def amount(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    total_amount = model.amount
    response_data ={}
    response_data['amount'] = total_amount

return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

ajax.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_client').change(function(){
        var query = $(this).val();
        console.log(query);
        $.ajax({
            url : "/amount/",
            type : "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                client_response : query
                },
            success: function(json) {
                document.getElementById('id_amount').value=json.amount;
            },
            failure: function(json) { 
                alert('Got an error dude');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

url.py
add corresponding line:

```
 url(r'^amount/$', 'main.views.amount', name='amount'),
```